# Reading chrome's dev tools (memory leaks)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I was reading [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) article to fix some memory leaks on a web app that i'm working on. One section is about detached DOMs, so I tried it myself and see below image result.

[image: chrome dev tools]

As you can see, detached DOMs eats 0%, so does that mean I don't have to worry with detached DOMs since they are not really contributing on the actual memory leaks?

Thanks